# How to get credentials-id for a docker registery

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have signed up for one of the public docker registries, so I've been given a username and password. I'm writing a Jenkins job which pulls an image from this repository, so I'm using the following command in my Jenkins pipeline

```
docker.withRegistry('https://registry.example.com', 'credentials-id')
```

However I don't know what I should put in as the `credentials-id`? How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This credentials-id Item is provided by the Jenkins credentials Plugin. It is documented here, e.g. https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/